# webpack angularjs function returns string instead of object

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, webpack

I am creating webpage with webpack and Ive got strange error.

> Data must be a valid JSON object. Received: "
> ....  Undefined
>   index: id

So, I checked my objects which i sending. Then, when my service to get ID returns something like this in console log:

```
ƒ (){
        return id;
    }
```

So, I know that I've to run function first, then html template. Where I can get the error if we are talking about webpack?

It's my app.js, where I configure service and templates with controllers:

```
const css = require('./src/style/app.scss');
var angular = require('angular'); 
var ngRoute = require('angular-route');

var ngModule = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);  
require('./src/js/contact')(ngModule);
require('./src/js/adminNetworks')(ngModule);
require('./src/js/automatic')(ngModule);
require('./src/js/login')(ngModule);
require('./src/js/program')(ngModule);
require('./src/js/register')(ngModule);
require('./src/js/main')(ngModule); 


ngModule.service('user', function(){
    var username;
    var loggedin = false;
    var id;

    this.getName = function(){
        return username;
    };

    this.setID = function(userID){
        id = userID;
    };
    this.getID = function(){
        return id;
    };

    this.isUserLoggedIn = function(){
        if(!!localStorage.getItem('login')){
            loggedin = true;
            var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login'));
            username = data.username;
            id = data.id;
        }
        return loggedin;
    };

    this.saveData = function(data){
        username = data.user;
        id = data.id;
        loggedin = true;
        localStorage.setItem('login', JSON.stringify({
            username: username,
            id: id
        }));
    };

    this.clearData = function(){
        localStorage.removeItem('login');
        username="";
        id="";
        loggedin = false;
    }

})

ngModule.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', 'user', function ($scope, user) {        
    $scope.aa = function(){
        console.log(user.get);
    }
}])


ngModule.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){ 
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); 
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/program', {
        templateUrl: 'program.html',
        controller: 'ProgramCtrl',
        resolve: {
            check: function($location, user){
                if(!user.isUserLoggedIn()){
                    $location.path('/');
                    alert('Musisz być zalogowany')
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .when('/administration', {
        templateUrl: 'adminNetworks.html',
        controller: 'NetworkCtrl'
    })
    .when('/automatic', {
        templateUrl: 'automatic.html',
        controller: 'AutomaticCtrl'
    })
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'contact.html',
        controller: 'ContactCtrl'
    })
    .when('/registry', {
        templateUrl: 'register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })
    .when('/logout', {
        resolve: {
            deadResolve: function($location, user){
                user.clearData();
                $location.path('/');
            }
        }
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
      });
});
```

Firstly, I thought, that it's because of load chunks like this:

```
 plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                title: 'Główna',
                hash: true, 
                allChunks: true,
                template: './src/html/index.html'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Main',
            hash: true,
            chunks: ['main'],
            filename: 'main.html',
            template: './src/html/main.html'
        }),
```

but when I removed chunks section, it's still the same.
Please at least for any ideas.

@Edit - my new pass sender:

```
module.exports = function(ngModule) {
    ngModule.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','user', function ($scope, $http, user) {  
               $scope.user = user.getName();
        console.log("LOCAL STORAGE");
        console.log(localStorage);


        $scope.newPass = function(){
            debugger;
            var password = $scope.newpassword;
            $http({
                url: 'http://localhost/webpack/updatePass.php',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                data: 'newPass='+password+'&id='+user.getID()                  
            }).then(function(response){
                if(response.data.status =='done') {
                    alert('Changed');
                }else {
                    alert('error');
                }      
            })
        }
    }])
}
```

Comment: the problem is probably in the `isUserLoggedIn` method of the service. Do a console.log() on the data that is in localstorage to see what it is.

Comment: When I logged in my localStorage object has: login:"{"username":"admin","id":"05532a81d47b6b1921f3d63e5aa2dae5"}".

Comment: @reptilicus I added to my question code of new password sender. When i debug it, id is undefined. getId method returns undefined too

Comment: login
:
"{"username":"admin","id":"5d9a2a1d25ace68bd728c586e5cd5043"}"

Comment: yeah thats a string. Its not getting parsed to JSON.

Comment: How can I fix this? I've got var data = JSON.parse in my method

Comment: I'd add in a `debugger` in that controller and figure out why the `user` service is not parsing the data in localStorage correctly